# How can I make the Fixed Sidebar wider for my HTML webpage? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

This currently shows a black sidebar on the left side of the webpage. I am having trouble making the sidebar wider to cover more of the left side of the page. I can adjust depending on the visibility of the page but I want to fix it.

Here is the current css code:

```
body {
  background-color: paleturquoise;
  margin-left: 240px;
}

.image-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-row img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}

figure {
  text-align: center;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #666;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#navbar p, #navbar a { 
   color: #808080;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear
Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. 
and
Question needs some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the #navbar is your sidebar? what do you mean: "sidebar wider to cover more of the left side of the page"? 
#navbar { ... width: 50px;...} that is a fix width ! Try with some as width: 10%